# react I would like to add Loading to the ternary operator parent tag

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I want to display the value of the ternary operator immediately after the loading message is displayed before the ternary operator is calculated.

But now the situation is rendering, Loading message is output, then `two` component text is output, then `one` component text is output.

I want to call the `loading component` message and then the `one component` message.

```
const one = () => {
 return (
  <>
   <p>one</p>
  </>
 ) 
}

const two = () => {
  return (
  <> 
   <p>two</p>
  </> 
 ) 
}
```

```
const button = (() => {
 
 const [expire, setExpire] = useState(false);
 const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false); 
  
 
  useEffect(() => {
    if (one) {
      setExpire(true)
    }
    return setLoading(true);
  }, [setExpire, one, setLoading])  

 return (
   <>
    {loading ? 
    <>
     {expire ? <one /> : <two />}
    </> 
    : <span>Loading</span>
   </>
 )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `const [expire, setExpire] = useState(true);`
then in `useEffect` check

```
if (!one) {
  setExpire(false)
}
```

It should solve your problem